# Diodes in an op-amp feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, common-emitter

Consider the following circuit:
[image]

(notice the 20 diodes in the feedback loop). If I analysed this correctly, the output from the common-emitter amplifier is just the input signal but inverted and with a gain of (10/1) = 10. In order to forward bias the diodes, I would need 20*0.6=12 V of output from the op amp, but it is connected to a 10V supply.

From this, the feedback loop must be cut off and so the output signal is just directly connected to the output of the common-emitter amplifier. Therefore, I immediately guessed that the output is just an inverted signal with a gain of 10 but the answer sheet to this problem says that the output is 0. Can someone point me in the right direction on why my analysis was flawed?

Comment: There's no dot on the junction of 8.8K/1.2K/Base/cap...

Comment: The opamp inverts the signal of course. The output of the opamp will go from max+ to max- (open loop gain). In neither opamp output condition can the chain of diodes conduct, so the output will be zero in the most simplistic case. However since the opamp input is no longer a virtual ground the output for some opamp types could be the input signal in series with 20k.

Comment: Is it possible "x20" doesn't mean 20 diodes? Could it mean something like a "B20" Zener? Then at least the circuit and the answer start to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the op amp output is at (nominally) 10 volts, the current through the diode string will be, as you realized, very close to zero. Then the op amp will have effectively no effect, and your analysis is correct.

The answer sheet is wrong. It is basically assuming that the op amp loop is working so as to keep the inverting input at zero volts, so with no current through the feedback resistor the output is asserted to be zero.

However, with the diodes not conducting, there is no feedback current to keep the inverting input at zero, so the answer sheet's assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no input current at DC because it has an AC coupling Capacitor. only Time variant signals reach the input and the Op-Amp has a rail to rail voltage of 20-volts. Let's say that an input of a time-varying signal passes the capacitor and its value is 2 volts. The 2 volts through the input resistor sends .2mA through the input resistor and the feedback resistor to make the output -2 so the Op-Amp could technically be at its Positive Rail in this circumstance.

But first, the Transistor has to revolve around 1.2 volts (10*(1.2/(1.2+8.8)) in AC and at 1.2 Volts the Emitter is at 0.6 volts and the current it generates through 1,000 ohms is .6mA, that amount is what must flow through the collector so the voltage at the Quiescent Current is 10-6= +4-Volts
@ 1.1 Base Voltage, The Emitter current is .5mA so Collector Voltage is 10-5= +5-Volts so the AC Voltage that potentially gets through the AC coupling cap is now +1 volt.

if the Input was 1 volt the Transistor wouldn't conduct (as the Vbe would be under 0.6 volts so no current through the emitter or Collector and the AC coupling cap is connected to the positive rail so the voltage at the input of the inverting input would never go farther positive than 1 volt. so there would never be a chance for it to get to even try an output of its positive rail of +10 volts -20*.6=-12 volts to get a Vout of -2 volts to flow through Rf and create an offsetting current of -.2mA because there would never be +.2mA at the input because when the transistor is shut off then it's certainly not a time-varying AC signal anymore.

Short answer: The Output is Zero Becuase the Input is Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to get you started. First, the x20 diodes are in parallel, which means that the voltage drop across the diodes will be less than just one diode.

If we are talking the DC bias of this circuit, we can ignore everything left of the capacitors, which leaves us with an opamp in negative gain configuration. Since there is no current flowing through the first 10k resistor, we can ignore that too. Which leaves us with a voltage follower with a diode and a 10k ohm resistor in the feedback path.

Because of the negative feedback, the inverting node of the opamp will be driven to 0V. Since there is no current flowing into the inverting node and thus no current flowing through the feedback resistor, the OUT node will also be at zero volts. So, I would say that the answer sheet is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Op Amp input impedance is much higher than the string of 10 diodes then it is unity gain and Vout=0.

If Ib= 1nA = diode current then the 10x diode drop will be ~1 uV or near 0V output.

[image].

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMgMIj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There will be some Op AMps with more input bias current than diode leakage and this will force the output to the supply rail.